# Python парсинг html: как получить HTML фрагмент, определяемый CSS селектором

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

Есть html код:

```
<div class="full-desc">

                                    <p></p><h2>Описание</h2>
      <b><br>
     <br>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.br>
     <br>
     <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</b>
    </ul></div>
```

Я делаю так

```
br = requests.get(сылка).text
bf = fromstring(br)
opisanie = bf.cssselect('div .full-desc')[0].text_content()
```

и выходит текст, а я хочу что бы было с тегами, так убирал text_content() и другие атрибуты из мануала http://lxml.de/tutorial.html но нечего не помогло как сделать что бы парсило с тегами?

Comment: По вашей же ссылке упоминается tostring

Comment: сделал так opisanie = bf.cssselect(OPISANIE)[0].tostring(html)
выходит ошибка AttributeError: 'HtmlElement' object has no attribute 'tostring'

Comment: По вашей же ссылке написано, как правильно использовать tostring, там есть рабочие примеры

Comment: забыл добавить from lxml import etree
теперь вместо данных выходят данные b'<div class="full-desc">\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<p/><h2>&#1054;&#1087;&#1080;&#1089;&#1072;&#1085;&#1080;&#1077; &#1087;&#1072;&#1088;&#1086;&#1082;&#1086;&#1085;&#1074;&#1077;&#1082;&#1090;&#1086;&#1084;&#1072;&#1090;&#1072; Rational CM Plus XS</h2>&#13;\n

Comment: И про это там тоже написано, но не буду вас больше мучать — попробуйте использовать tostring вот так: `etree.tostring(..., encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8')`

Comment: все помогло, спасибо